# Woocommerce Login Redirect to old domain

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, login

I move webpage to new domain.

- change in phpmyadmin  _option _> new domain

Everything is good but when I click in my account page (woocommerce) link go to old page. How to change this link to stay in new domain woocommerce?

Comment: Have you contacted WooCommerce support or asked in a WooCommerce community? WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugins are off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their communities.

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is correct, updating the wp_options in phpmyadmin is correct but its only step one.

You will need to update all occurrences of your old domain with the new.

Assuming that your DB prefix is wp_.

You will fine that the table wp_posts contains all posts/pages, under the guid column you will find all of the permalinks, i'm sure that when you will navigate there you will see your old domain.

To update the guid you can use the following sql

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

Another option is to use a plugin.

Better search and replace does a great job with changing those setting, you can also bulk update/search multiple tables at ones.

IMPORTANT!!! Always backup your DB before doing any changes! even if you are 100% sure that everything will work; BACKUP ANYWAY!